# What is syntax of nested property of MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am using MSBuild.

I am getting the value of the `Person_1` through the `$(Person_1)`. How can I get the value of the `Name` subelement of `Person_2`? I need the syntax.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Person_1>Bob</Person_1>
  <Person_2>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Person_2>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Properties and ItemGroups.

Properties are simple named values, ItemGroups are items with an identity and with properties. You can not use both in the same way.

Properties are defined as :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <name>value</name>
</Propertygroup>
```

and are accessed by using the `$(name)` syntax.

Item groups are defined as:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Item Include="item1">
        <ItemPropery>value</ItemProperty>
    </Item>
</ItemGroup>
```

and are accessed by using this syntax: `%(Item.ItemProperty)`.

See also [this reference for the 'intuitive' syntax](http://rationalgeek.com/blog/msbuild-propertygroup-itemgroup-item-metadata-and-crazy-syntax/)

Comment: No, I think you are not right. Look here the "Storing XML in properties" chapter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx

Comment: Hmm, that would still be the same problem doesn't it? Instead of a literal text value, you are now storing an xml value in your (flat) property. The syntax is misleading, but to msbuild this is still a simple property with an single (in this case xml) value. Note that the example specificly limits the use of the constructed xml value: `Properties can contain arbitrary XML, which can help in passing values to tasks or displaying logging information.`. It does not say that you can read the xml content using an msbuild syntax.

Answer (score 3):

RE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx
A property that contains XML is simply that. You cannot access parts of the content just because it is XML. To understand this do the following;

```
<PropertyGroup> 
   <MyProperty>
       <PropertyContentXML>
           <InnerXML1>Blablabla</InnerXML1>
           <InnerXML2>More blablabla</InnerXML2>
       </PropertyContentXML>
   </MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup> 
<Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="$(MyProperty)" />
</Target>
```

The output of this will be:

```
<PropertyContentXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <InnerXML1>Blablabla</InnerXML1>
        <InnerXML2>More blablabla</InnerXML2>
</PropertyContentXML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something advanced, like an inline task:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXmlToItem" 
           TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
           AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <Xml Required="true"/>
    <Elements ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Output="true"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Using Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Using Namespace="System.Xml" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[  
        using (var xr = new XmlTextReader(Xml, XmlNodeType.Element,
            new XmlParserContext(null, null, null, XmlSpace.Default))) {

            xr.Namespaces = false;
            xr.MoveToContent();
            var items = new List<ITaskItem>();
            while (!xr.EOF) {
                if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
                    var item = new TaskItem(xr.Name);
                    var text = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) {
                        item.SetMetadata("text", text);
                    }
                }
                xr.Read();
            }
            Elements = items.ToArray();
        }
    ]]>
  </Code>
</Task>
```

The task reads the XML elements and creates items from it. The text is transformed into metadata.

You can then write a task like this:

```
<Target Name="DeconstructPropertyXml">
  <TransformXmlToItem Xml="$(Person_2)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Elements" ItemName="Person_2I"/>
  </TransformXmlToItem>
  <Message Text="%(Person_2I.Identity) = %(Person_2I.text)" Importance="high"/>
</Target>
```

Which should just output `Name = Bob`.

The same way you could add additional metadata from attributes, etc.